# My cocoapods shows as objective c but it's swift and metrics show language null

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

my cocoapod DYBadgeButton (https://cocoapods.org/pods/DYBadgeButton) shows no errors when I trunk push it to cocoa pods but there is no "expand button" and I can't find it under swift but only under objective c.  it's written in swift 4. Github didn't detect the language correctly at first (it was categorised as Shell) but I added a gitattributes file and now it detects it as Swift. Even publishing a new version after this change didn't change anything on cocoapods.org. When I click on docs it shows the 404 error and even re-parsing doesn't change anything. I would like to delete the pod and trunk push it again but it seems there is no way to do this.

> {"github":{"subscribers":null,"stargazers":null,"forks":null,"contributors":null,"open_issues":null,"open_pull_requests":null,"created_at":"2017-12-25
>   14:28:10 UTC","updated_at":"2017-12-25 14:28:11
>   UTC","language":null,"closed_issues":null,"closed_pull_requests":null},"cocoadocs":null,"stats":{"download_total":0,"download_week":0,"download_month":0,"app_total":0,"app_week":0,"tests_total":0,"tests_week":0,"created_at":"2017-12-26
>   09:16:00 UTC","updated_at":"2017-12-26 09:16:00
>   UTC","extension_week":0,"extension_total":0,"watch_week":0,"watch_total":0,"pod_try_week":0,"pod_try_total":0,"is_active":false}}

thanks for any hints